# How to export the paths of folders which are inside a folder to an txt with batch or cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a folder that have folders root/sound/weapon/ak47, root/sound/weapon/m1. root/sound/weapon/m4a1 etc. ak47,m1,m4a1 folders is in root/sound/weapon.

I want to export these paths to .txt with cmd.

For example:

```
root/sound/weapon/ak47
root/sound/weapon/m4a1
root/sound/weapon/m1
```

I know that `DIR root\sound\weapons /B /O >Names.txt` exports the names ak47,m1,m4a1 to a .txt but I can't think how I can also get the paths.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `/s` argument will include sub-directories in the listing (which you may not want), but a side-effect is that it also displays the full path to all files (which you want):

So try something like `DIR root\sound\weapons /B /S >Names.txt`.

Another alternative (which doesn't include subfolders) could be to create a batch file and use [`For`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html).  Something like:

```
@echo off
if exist files.txt del files.txt
for /f %%a in ('dir %1 /b') do @echo %1\%%a >> files.txt
```

Run the batch file and give the path you want the DIR for, e.g.: `myBatch.bat c:\Path`

Comment: Add `/AD` for paths only too or else you also get files.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to export these paths to .txt with cmd

Note:

- On Windows the path delimeter is `\` not `/`.

**From a `cmd` shell**:

If you just want the path:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %~pnxi >> Names.txt
```

Example:

```
F:\test>for /f %i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %~pnxi >> Names.txt

F:\test>type Names.txt
\test\root\sound\weapon\ak47
\test\root\sound\weapon\m1
\test\root\sound\weapon\m4a1
```

If you want the drive as well, then use:

```
for /f %i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %~fi >> Names.txt
```

Example:

```
F:\test>for /f %i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %~fi >> Names.txt

F:\test>type Names.txt
F:\test\root\sound\weapon\ak47
F:\test\root\sound\weapon\m1
F:\test\root\sound\weapon\m4a1
```

**In a batch file**:

Replace `%` with `%%`.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %%~pnxi >> Names.txt
```

Or:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d root\sound\weapon /b /s') do @echo %%~fi >> Names.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.